# R running with Command Line Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"

Tags: java, r, command-line

I am using R just to plot graph calculated from another executable jar file(vdjtools-1.0.7) compiled into Java.

For example when I run into the Command Line:

`C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\mixcr-1.7.1\R\R-3.2.4revised\bin\java –Xmx3g –jar vdjtools-1.0.7.jar PlotFancySpectratype inputFile.txt outputFile`

It runs the program vdjtools properly because I have a correct output txt file but it doesn’t give a pdf file generated by R with the plot like it should:

> ...[Fri Apr 01 12:00:58 CEST 2016 PlotFancySpectratype] Writing output and plotting data
>
> [RUtil] Executing Rscript ebe147b7-6ae1-4d23-9d40-17832213fe29_fancy_spectratype.r Plot.fancyspectra.txt Plot.fancyspectra.pdf Clonotype TRUE
>
> [ERROR] Erreur : '\U' non suivi de chiffres hexadécimaux dans la chaîne de caractères débutant ""C:\U"
>   Exécution arrêtée

I know that R doesn’t like ‘\’ and it should be instead ‘/’ or ‘\’ but when I write the path to directory with ‘/’ or ‘\’ into the command line, it gives the same result..

Hope someone can help me..

Answer (score 0):

I will use some technical terms in my answer. I hope you are ok with that.

Well, the error is occuring because of the fact that R treats '\' as part of escape character. That's why it is taking '\U' as a single unit and showing the error.

Solution:

1) As you mentioned in your question, use '/' instead of '\'

or

2) Use '\\' instead of '\'.

Comment: If I do that, the same error occurs because the command line changes automatically the '/' or '\\' into '\'

Comment: Then I think You should try adding 'C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\mixcr-1.7.1\R\R-3.2.4revised\bin\' to the PATH Environment Variable, restart the command line and retrying with command 'java –Xmx3g –jar vdjtools-1.0.7.jar PlotFancySpectratype inputFile.txt outputFile'

Comment: I referred to one of the tutorials for vdjtools.jar [http://vdjtools-doc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html](http://vdjtools-doc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). In that, it is written "Output prefix could be either an output directory name (if ended with /) or an output file prefix." Please check if you can get away with just "outputFile".

Comment: I just tried this "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\mixcr-1.7.1\R\R-3.2.4revised\bin>java -Xmx3g -jar C:/Users/Lucy/Desktop/mixcr-1.7.1/R/R-3.2.4revised/bin/vdjtools-1.0.7.jar PlotFancySpectratype InputFile.txt C:/Users/Lucy/Desktop/mixcr-1.7.1/R/R-3.2.4revised/bin/OutputFile" and it doesn't work either (still same error)